# Specify Next.js build directory in build command?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Originally, I had my distDir set to a folder within my Firebase Functions directory for deployment, however, the duplication of React when running the app in dev mode led to some errors, so I've had to comment it out.

Is there a way to specify the `next build` commands output directory within the command? Like `next build dir='../functions/next'`.

Or is there a way to separate dev builds directory (from the `next` command) from the production builds (`next build`) within the config?

Answer (score 6):

I found following solution for this problem:

You can set custom environment variable that decides where your build will be generated:

```
BUILD_DIR=myBuilds/buildXYZ yarn build
```

OR

```
BUILD_DIR=myBuilds/buildXYZ npm build
```

In the next.config.js you can use your environment variable like this:

```
module.exports = {
  distDir: process.env.BUILD_DIR || '.next',
}
```

Now your build will be dynamically generated in the `myBuilds/buildXYZ` directory defined in the `BUILD_DIR` variable.

One thing to notice: If you want to use the `next export` command (or any other command using the build directory), you should also add the environment variable before it, e.g.:

```
BUILD_DIR=myBuilds/buildXYZ yarn export
```

Comment: ENV" must be lower case.
module.exports = {
  distDir: process.env.BUILD_DIR || '.next',
}

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/1513, this may need you to update to the next version. But it looks like they added a feature to next.config.js file. All you have to do is add the destination for your dist:

```
module.exports = {
  options: {
    dist: '.next'
  }
}
```

Haven't tested it, but it was successfully merged to master and marked as resolved.

Comment: That's not the solution that was just a feature request.